# Is there a console command to tell Mac book to go to sleep?

Tags: macos, shell

I'd like to

```
$   sleep
```

Then my mac book would go to sleep, just like Apple Icon -> Sleep on the top left of the screen.

I guess it may involve shell scripting. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/22/sleep-a-mac-from-the-command-line/

Comment: [pmset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pmset)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's really simple to sleep the computer in the terminal. The command [(sourced from this SO post)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159440/187213) is:

```
pmset displaysleepnow
```

But if you want a simple shell script to do the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
pmset displaysleepnow
```

Save this as `sleepy` (not `sleep`, it already exists but completely unrelated), then `chmod +x sleepy`, add it to your `$PATH`, and you're done.

Comment: perfect! Thank you!